# Custom Profile Fields move from BBpress to BuddyPress

Tags: custom-field, buddypress, profiles, bbpress

I used before only **bbpress** forum but I decided to add also **buddypress**. I have old **bbpress** user profile custom fields that I created.

How to make they works on buddypress user profiles?

I don't want to use default **buddypress** fields creator because I want to display some extra stuff like icons and extra text based on selected value, and default profile fields creator doesn't offer this.

Here is code that I used:

```
// Display on User Edit Page
add_action("bbp_user_edit_after_contact", "edit_gender_field");
function edit_gender_field()
{
    // a random selection of genders
    $genders = array("Male", "Female");
    // selected gender, if any
    $user_gender = bbp_get_displayed_user_field('u_gender');
    ?>
    <label for="gender"><?php _e('Gender'); ?></label>
    <select name="gender" id="gender">
        <option value="">Select your gender</option>
        <?php foreach ($genders as $gender) : ?>
            <option <?php selected($user_gender, $gender); ?>><?php echo esc_attr($gender); ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
    <?php
}

// Save when updating
// Our profile
add_action("personal_options_update", "save_gender_value");
// Other users' profiles
add_action("edit_user_profile_update", "save_gender_value");

function save_gender_value($user_id)
{
    // exclude profile.php/user-edit update
    if (is_admin()) return;
    // update preference
    if (isset($_POST['gender']) && $_POST['gender']) {
        return update_user_meta($user_id, "u_gender", sanitize_text_field($_POST['gender']));
    } else {
        return delete_user_meta($user_id, "u_gender");
    }
}


// Display on User Profile Page
add_action("bbp_user_profile_gender", "display_gender_value");

function display_gender_value()
{
    // selected gender, if any
    $user_gender = bbp_get_displayed_user_field('u_gender');
    // making sure user has set their gender first
    if (!trim($user_gender)) return;
    // all good
    if ($user_gender == 'Male') {
        return printf('Some stuff to display if user is %s', esc_attr($user_gender));
    }
    if ($user_gender == 'Female') {
        return printf('Some stuff to display if user is %s', esc_attr($user_gender));
    }
}
```

I guess that I should change action `personal_options_update`. I found in web something like that `xprofile_data_before_save` but it doesn't work.

Also I think that I should change `bbp_get_displayed_user_field`. I changed to `xprofile_get_field_data` but it doesn't work too.

Maybe I'm doing something wrong. Please help me if you know how to make it work.